# browsing to my VisualBasic2010 created web app's URL using IE8 won't persist cookies 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, internet-explorer, cookies

All other browsers (FireFox, Chrome, etc.) cookies persist ok.
NOTE:  Using IE8 to browse to my web app by using the web app's IP address instead of URL will persist cookies ok.

My IE8 browser options are set to Accept All Cookies.

This fails on IE8 on more than one computer.

I can see in IE8 > `Dev Tools > Cache > View Cookie Info` that the cookies are not getting stored.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. How does going to `example.com` relate to *your* web application?

Comment: Sorry.  stackoverflow automatically added the confusing "example.com".
I just re-edited the post completely with latest research.

Comment: Also:  please click up arrow if this is clear now -- the negative arrows got me banned from new questions.

Comment: I have removed my downvote but the question is still not that clear. Are you saying that cookies are saved ok using IE8 with the IP address but not the hostname?

Comment: Thanks for removing.
Yes, to your question.
Please note answer that I have below.
And please up-arrow votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: The problem went away after I redid my methods for storing cookies...

```
sub update_cookie_string( cookie_string, cookie_subkey  )

    dim cookie_object as HttpCookie     
    if request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME ) is nothing then   ' PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME not at browser?
        cookie_object = new httpcookie( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )           ' init cookie object as cookie named: PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME
    else
        cookie_object = request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )          ' Read cookie named PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME from page from browser
    End If

    cookie_object.Values( cookie_subkey ) = cookie_string       ' Update cookie_subkey with new value cookie_string
    cookie_object.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)           ' set expiration for a long time
    response.Cookies.add( cookie_object )                   ' Send it back to browser for storage there.
end sub



' Retrieve stored cookie_subkey.
function get_cookie_string( byval cookie_subkey  ) 
    dim cookie_object as HttpCookie     
    if  request.cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME ) is nothing then  ' PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME not at browser?
        get_cookie_string = ""
    else
        get_cookie_string = Request.Cookies( PROGRAM_COOKIE_NAME )( cookie_subkey )  ' Return string value of cookie_subkey 
    End If
```